# Segmentation Fault in C when I try to read a file

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I want to read 3 columns from a csv file, but when a run the program I receive Segmentation Fault error.
I don't how what to do to make this run.
I don't see a problem.

This is just a part of a program

```
int main()
{
    FILE *fptr;
    fptr = fopen("Ist_DL_Ap_Masura.csv", "r");
    if (fptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error!");
        return 0;
    }
    char buff[300];
    int data[5] = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        fgets(buff, 300, (FILE *)fptr);
    int i = 0;
    int j = 1;
    int virgula = 0;
    uint8_t aux = 0;
    while (virgula != 3)
    {
        if (buff[i] == ',')
            virgula++;
        i++;
    }
    while (virgula != 6)
    {
        if (buff[i] != ',')
        {
            aux = ChatToHex(buff[i]);
            data[j] = data[j] << 4;
            data[j] = data[j] + aux;
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            j++;
            i++;
        }
    }
    int aux2 = data[3];
    data[3] = data[2];
    data[2] = aux2;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("%x ", data[i]);
    }
    fclose(fptr);
    return 1;
   }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. First step should be to run your program in a debugger. It will tell you where the segfault happened. Then you can inspect values of the involved variables for expected/valid content.

Comment: You should show the content of your input file. At least the first few lines.

Comment: What do you think it will happen if `buff` contain only one (for example) comma ? What value `i` will be get ?

Comment: Why the fishy cast `(FILE *)fptr`? Is this the real code?

Comment: What is `ChatToHex`? Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve);

Comment: This loop does not make any sense: `while (virgula != 6)` You never change `virgula` in the loop body.

Comment: Off-topci: No need to cast `fptr` to `FILE*` *again* if it *is* already... Repeating `300` literally for buffer size is not a good idea, you might change original buffer size but forget to adjust the second occurrence. Better use `sizeof(buf)` instead, or `sizeof(buf)/sizeof(*buf)` if `buf` isn't an array to char any more.

Comment: `while (virgula != 6)`: this loop never ends, and `i`and `j` increase idefinitely until you start to access memory which is no lonnger your's. Use your debugger (possibly investing some time in learning) and you'll see what happens

Comment: @Jabberwocky you have right, I forgot to increase the virgula variable